# Run JavaScript and Django tests in one command?

Tags: django, backbone.js

I have a Django project that runs Backbone in the front-end.

Currently I do this to run my Django tests:

```
python manage.py test
```

And this to run my JavaScript tests:

```
npm test
```

What's the best way to have a single command that does both?

Comment: You mean something like `python manage.py test; npm test` or `python manage.py test && npm test`?

Comment: @str yes, that works, but I was wondering if a makefile or something like that would let me combine them... and perhaps install the test dependencies too if needed?